# $locationChangeStart is no longer getting called

Tags: javascript

This all worked fine for a long time, but just stopped  I am besides myself as to why  $locationChangeStart is no longer getting called.

The only thing I have changed is converted our tests over to use Jasmine 2.0.1 framework.  But even when I remove that framework from the Visual studio project  it still doesn't work.  The odd thing is that it will sometimes get called in the tests.

Something is interfering with this, but what?  I debugged into the $on method and I can see the listener being added to the listeners collection.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.  Thanks, Beth

This is the code that I have in the very beginning of our controller file.  In debug I see the listener being loaded but then it never gets called.

app.controller('someXYZCtrl', ['$scope', 'resourceFactory', '$http', '$routeParams', '$filter', '$location', '$timeout', function someXYZCtrl($scope, resourceFactory, $http, $routeParams, $filter, $location, $timeout) {

//alert the user when they are navigating away from the page

```
 var navigationConfirmed = false;
 $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
 if (navigationConfirmed) {
            return;
 }

 event.preventDefault();
  bootbox.confirm(" ...... ", function (result) {
            if (result) {
                navigationConfirmed = true;
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    var hash = next.substr(next.indexOf('#') + 1);
                    $location.path(hash);
                });

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$rootScope.$on()` instead of `$scope.$on()`? Just a hunch, your code seems fine.

Comment: Yes, earlier, $rootScope isn't recognized - an error is thrown.  Not sure why, I am new to controllers and javascript.  Maybe this is the issue?